# Android app links opening in apps when navigating on browser

Tags: android, browser, navigation, android-app-links

This is what I am facing right now. I have certain pages configured as Android app links in manifest file of my app. They work as expected when I search for those pages in Google and click on those links resulting in opening the corresponding app pages. My issue is when I am browsing the same pages on Chrome OS browser on my phone and try to navigate to the same links in the browser itself, they still open the app instead of navigating in the browser itself.

So for example if I have a Android app link in manifest file as scheme://host/path/ When I type this link in browser or open browser with scheme://host and navigate to path, it opens the app instead of keeping the user in the browser itself. How do I prevent user from opening the app when navigating in the browser itself?